# Angular interface from mongoose schema

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, interface, schema

Please help to figure it out how to make proper Angular interface from db model

Have following schema on backend:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const incomeSchema = new Schema({   
    income: {
        type: Number
    },
    incomeDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})


const userSchema = new Schema({
    username :{
        type: String,        
    },
    website: {
        sitename: {
            type :String
        },        
        income: [incomeSchema]
    }    
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Is that correct way to write  Angular interface ? Can't make it work :(

```
export class userInterface  {
    _id: String
    username: String
    website: {
        sitename: String,
        income: [
            {
                income : Number
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is unsuitable for declaring a type that represents an HTTP response because the deserialized JSON values that result from HTTP requests will never be instances of a class. An interface is a perfect candidate for it.

**Solution**

```
interface IncomeData{
income:number;
incomeDate:Date;
}

interface Website{
sitename: string;
incomeData:Array<IncomData>;
}

export interface User{
    id: string;
    username: string;
    website:Website;
}
```

[How to design a Typescript Model for Response Returned By HttpClient library in Angular.](https://medium.com/@erVikas1/how-to-design-a-typescript-model-for-response-returned-by-httpclient-library-in-angular-a5e7f6c6b110)